# how to solve rsa related message attack with exponent of 65537?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, ctf

c1 = ([message] + b'good')^e mod N 
c2 = ([message] + b'hello')^e mod N

we got c1,c2 and e, N.how to get message recover

e.g:

```
from Crypto.Util.number import *

N = getPrime(1024) * getPrime(1024)
e = 65537
m = b'asdasdasdasdasdasdasdad'
print(N)

print(pow(bytes_to_long(m) + bytes_to_long(b'hello'), e, N))
print(pow(bytes_to_long(m) + bytes_to_long(b'good'), e, N))

# 13824259202707707704698945750555650188923092989268878762501795757989658824989810874884266999337165342953213211887061514825958553609144117703703258701326022555786135220477315399712884125614387173381827614381256300829440707734494820382614289703908717491613414182027679499244735432109060499149532381212541977764000110184519399366525605760733146179772941429335256079914560952785133589850388762981579475642697758871309468524199989272654149503691316057495226800070232198670430646266325131194854572267338487885035101469575839387407242537184807389659155489522800266906762308283506648079055576871122888512049475856330890001343
# 8276659109712793815299578561719138578174632968651765806041202217454912208960034861689360987329311934883429921704719276734783502306194357901541231165498953390016674194748506249298549911771734899753148678798552104754999924151283524844665822574622839869787064551474267788166961708626565174688777456346982873550222301030207711832604295851347969452338879329997396351375967501075989830884016503399111439211560006966836981816154790123070674190106461105668194452404913979853606956887928831700424160777167891676755674297360337554607504753418365643045588301072415879765662558357415118404821285358454161314770144838910923623504
# 12062529732270479369398408885987121015035665116730823919415100374357168027361875295561106591018597251449600246188613002097103212665616638658219288950827495971784194429969249895507132940672081924143164246070195738418425526032150020095433941736897502046253164728866258960451123211291798117834562763926759386287252564794804678055732450470110455829664228632583208321124476416193489413745132190993800532396985948065271318259684439260205668490905514290180662532835602885190966567491432319734167361123863401995933808462898545858708457817527307705396477763226807528727397866105985550723953556595591642168706497014266952344649
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a solvable problem? A simpler form of this problem is: solve for m given pow(m, 65537, N) and pow(m+1, 65537, N). In your case m is way too big to compute the integer 65537th root and get m back, so I don't immediately see how to solve this.

Comment: however, it is a challenge in a CTF competition，i think it needs coppersmith method to solve.